# Switching Relay with NPN and PNP transistors

Tags: arduino, pnp

I'm designing a locker system using Arduino.
Due to system requirement, two IOs will be used control the relay, and only when two IOs are ON, then the relay will be triggered.

- PNP = BC807
- NPN = BC817
- Coil = 720 ohm, 20 mA
- Diode = 1N4148

My question is will PNP be switched on/off reliably?
Any risk to consider here?

Any suggestions are welcome.

[image: design draft]

Comment: What you mean by ON state of the IO? Logic low or logic high?

Comment: Logic High (5V) on Arduino output pin

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Arduino to control the coil, why are you trying to implement a logical AND with BJTs?

Just keep the NPN transistor and write

```
if(A && B) digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);
else digitalWrite(pin, LOW);
```

in your code. `A` and `B` should correspond to the activation conditions of the IO pins in your original schematic.

Answer (score 1):

No. You will have a high-side fail.

[image]

*Figure 1. When V<sub>SS</sub> > +5 V (or whatever your micro-controller uses) there will be a base current leakage path and Q1 will turn on. Image source: [High-side driver fail](http://lednique.com/gpio-high-side-driver-fail/).*

[image]

*Figure 2. The solution to the high-side driver fail.*

However, as Dmitry pointed out the AND function should be done in the micro-controller rather than externally.

Comment: Do you want some feedback for this answer? If not, I'll delete this comment in 1 hour.

Comment: Go ahead, Harry.

Comment: I like fig 1, that's spot on. Perfect part of this answer, a little bit sloppy because it's not the same load, but the problematic concept is the same. Fig 2 however is promoting an unnecessarily *complicated* circuit. The PNP doesn't have to be there, and *again*, slightly *sloppy* because it's not the same load. The *more correct* way would be to show an NMOS (logic level) + relay + flyback diode. Sure, I'm pedantic, but that's who I am. And then to be further pedantic, show flyback with resistor, flyback without resistor, but that's over the top. I would give +1 if it was only NPN or NMOS.

Comment: @HarrySvensson, you are really out of line here. The question is whether upper pnp transitor will switch or not, and the answer clearly explains why not, never. The type of load has nothing to do with this whatsoever. Actually, it probably should be mentioned that the PNP will be always ON regardless of state of upper GPIO, and the circuit will still function, but not to the silly requirement of having two GPIO to control the relay.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, @Harry. My answer *only* addresses the high-side driving issue and I used an image I had created already. (I think you mean "lazy" rather than "sloppy". I think it's nice and neat!) Can you elaborate in your own answer how to do the high-side switch without the PNP? I'm interested.

Comment: @Ale..chenski  & Transistor Hmm, I did ask, oh well. - Yes, the question is "*My question is will PNP be switched on/off reliably?*", so it looks like OP is open to suggestions. Instead of answering this slightly XY-question on OP's terms. Maybe it would be better to show how it's *properly* done. Which would be without any high-side switch. The only reason for why that is a requirement (I think) is because OP wanted some logical AND function, which Transistor said could be done in software. meaning that the high-side switch = unnecessary. - But sure, maybe I was stepping out of line, sorry.

Comment: @Harry: That's fine, thanks, but can we see your high-side switch without the PNP?

Comment: @Transistor If I was forced to use high-side switching. Then it would be as you did in fig 2, but maybe with MOSFETs instead of BJT's. But I wouldn't use high-side switching for this, instead I'd use low side switching, which we should recommend to OP. Like sure, you can win the battle, and lose the war.

Comment: Transistor, you probably need to replace the "R2 with LED" in your illustrations with some more generic box and call it "load". Then there will be less questions and more focus on the issue with control (or lack thereof).

Comment: Thanks @Transistor. I think you are right. I could sense that there's something wrong with my circuit, but couldn't figure out where. This circuit is just part of the bigger system. The arduino will be doing Row-Column matrix switching, in order to control 100+ relays. Only one relay will be activated at anytime.  One IO switches relay -ve to GND, and another IO switches relay +ve to 12V. It's similar concept to Keypad scanning, just that in my case, it will be output, instead input reading.

Comment: @Kean: Thank you for your comment. A relay matrix presents other challenges. You can get sneak paths through the matrix giving strange results unless you add a diode in series with each relay. See [my article](http://lednique.com/display-technology/multiplexed-display/) which explains this in the context of LEDs (again). I suggest that for 100 relays you should create a 100-long shift register and direct drive each relay from a single output. You could then use the very common relay boards available at low cost. What are you switching?

Comment: Interesting article. I would never thought of the sneak path issue. It's 12V  mini solenoid for opening cabinet door. I will make a simple breadboard prototype to test it. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @Kean: If you use the shift-register idea then you can use a simple NPN or MOSFET switch in the negative rail only and direct-drive the solenoids. *Much* simpler and very easy to debug.

Answer (score 0):

No this will not work. You will need another NPN to control the PNP transistor. Also the choise of the diode... use a bigger one lets say a 1N4007 or something like that